# Having trouble uploading file in GitLab using php

Tags: php, gitlab

I'm sorry if I broke a rule or something. So I'm working on a website which is hosted on `GitLab`. What I'm trying to do is upload the user-selected image into the server, however, I'm facing an error that says `permission denied`.
[image: error-image]

Also, I am new to whole `GitLab` thing and have started working on it recently. They just gave us a git repo to work on.

Comment: It might be because the permissions for FileUpload have been set to false in GitLab. So could you check it once?

Comment: What is the code at line 404 of get_document_list_client_admin.php?

Comment: Please replace the image with the plain text of the error message.

Comment: The one starts with DC is just a token number. And Markus Its my first question didn't knew.